# How to filter 3 dimension array of object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So I was supposed to filter the 3D array of objects based on the object name that contains a text by user input. The output should be the 1 flat array and the parent array should be included as well, The matching object should be at any level of depth.

here is the data model:

```swift
let data = [
    Category(
        id: "1",
        name: "Stationary",
        iconImageUrl: nil,
        parent: nil,
        tree: 1,
        rootId: 1,
        child: [
            Category(
                id: "2",
                name: "Office Stationary",
                iconImageUrl: nil,
                parent: 1,
                tree: 2,
                rootId: 1,
                child: [
                    Category(id: "3", name: "Pen", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "4", name: "Pencil", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "5", name: "Ruler", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "6", name: "Paper", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil)
                ],
                rgbColor: nil
            ),
            Category(
                id: "7",
                name: "Home Stationary",
                iconImageUrl: nil,
                parent: 1,
                tree: 2,
                rootId: 1,
                child: [
                    Category(id: "8", name: "Telephone", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "9", name: "Fax", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "10", name: "Komputer", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                    Category(id: "11", name: "Laptop", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil)
                ],
                rgbColor: nil
            )
        ],
        rgbColor: nil
    )
]
```

for now, I was come up with something like this, but it reduces the performance of my app. cause it's using for loop I'm guessing

```swift
    var searchText = "pen"
    var filteredCategories: [Category] = []
    // Loop 1
    for parent in data.value {
        if let child = parent.child {
            // Loop 2
            for firstChild in child {
                if let child = firstChild.child {
                    // Loop 3
                    for secondChild in child {
                        // Check if the last array contains search text
                        if secondChild.name!.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                            // Check if the result has already 1st array so it wont duplicates
                            if !filteredCategories.contains(where: { $0.name == parent.name }) {
                                filteredCategories.append(parent)
                            }
                                // Check if the result has already contain 2nd array so it wont duplicates
                            if !filteredCategories.contains(where: { $0.name == firstChild.name }) {
                                filteredCategories.append(firstChild)
                            }
                            filteredCategories.append(secondChild)
                        }
                    }
                }
                if firstChild.name!.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                    if !filteredCategories.contains(where: { $0.name == parent.name }) {
                        filteredCategories.append(parent)
                    }
                    if !filteredCategories.contains(where: { $0.name == firstChild.name }) {
                        filteredCategories.append(firstChild)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if parent.name!.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
            if !filteredCategories.contains(where: { $0.name == parent.name }) {
                filteredCategories.append(parent)
            }
        }
    }
```

The result should be like this:

```swift
let result = [
    Category(
        id: "1",
        name: "Stationary",
        iconImageUrl: nil,
        parent: nil,
        tree: 1,
        rootId: 1,
        child: [
            Category(
                id: "2",
                name: "Office Stationary",
                iconImageUrl: nil,
                parent: 1,
                tree: 2,
                rootId: 1,
                child: [
                        Category(id: "3", name: "Pen", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                        Category(id: "4", name: "Pencil", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                        Category(id: "5", name: "Ruler", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                        Category(id: "6", name: "Paper", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil)
                ],
                rgbColor: nil
            ),
        ],
        rgbColor: nil),
    Category(
        id: "2",
        name: "Office Stationary",
        iconImageUrl: nil,
        parent: 1,
        tree: 2,
        rootId: 1,
        child: [
                Category(id: "3", name: "Pen", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                Category(id: "4", name: "Pencil", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                Category(id: "5", name: "Ruler", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
                Category(id: "6", name: "Paper", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil)
        ],
        rgbColor: nil
    ),
    Category(id: "3", name: "Pen", iconImageUrl: nil, parent: 2, tree: 3, rootId: 1, child: nil, rgbColor: nil),
]
```

Comment: Do not show or link to pictures of code. This is text. Copy and paste the data model into the question.

Comment: Also please try clarify what the question is. Give example input, desired output, and what is going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: hi matt thanks for the input, sorry for the mistake I already updated my question hopefully it was clear enough

Comment: Cool thanks. But I don't get the logic by which the input is supposed to generate the output. Can you explain in words what the goal is?

Comment: So I was given a search text and I was supposed to filter the 3D array by their name based on that text. The output should be the 1 flat array and the parent array should be included as well

Comment: So in the example the first step would be to search for "pen" as the name (or in the name) of a Category at any depth? Or is it known in advance that we only need to look at depth 3?

Comment: yup it would be to search for an object name that contains "pen" in any depth but that object parent should be included as well

Comment: Is it known that there is only one such category? That is, when I find the "pen" category can I stop?

Comment: nope it could be many of category as well as long the object name contains "pen", but there should be no duplicate category

Comment: Unfortunately, we couldn't redefine the category because the category model came from API JSON OBJECT

Comment: Off topic but why let an external API decide how you design your model objects? Why not create the design that suits you best and write some conversion code to map from api design and your design? (You don't have to answer, it's more of a rhetorical question)

Comment: This code could be remedied with higher order functions, but in the future if you run into cases where large loops like this are necessary, your code would benefit a lot from `guard`s and early returns instead of deeply nested `if` statements like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution where I make the filtering simpler by first converting the data structure into a dictionary, this is made with the assumption that `id` is the unique identifier for `Category`

This function creates the dictionary

```
func flatten(categories: [Category]) -> [String: Category] {
    var result = [String: Category]()
    for category in categories {
        result[category.id] = category
        if let children = category.child {
            let temp = flatten(categories: children)
            result.merge(temp, uniquingKeysWith: { (cat1, _) in return cat1 })
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

and then we use it to filter

```
let all = flatten(categories: data)
let found = all.mapValues(\.name).filter { $0.value == "Pen" }
```

Then to generate the expected output (although perhaps not in the right order) we make use of the fact that both the parent and root `Category` is given for a `Category`

```
var result = [Category]()
for key in found.keys {
    guard let category = all[key] else { continue }
    result.append(category)

    if let parentId = category.parent, let parent = all["\(parentId)"] {
        result.append(parent)
    }

    if let root = all["\(category.rootId)"] {
        result.append(root)
    }
}
```

If the order of the elements in the array is important that shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Comment: @DarindraRamantyaKhadifa but that shouldn’t be to hard to fix yourself,  I have answered your question about how to filter and create an array of the results including parents so please respect that. Beside the question doesn’t mention anything on how to sort so I wouldn’t know how to do it.

Comment: This `flatten` looks like a recursive "key by" operation. You could use [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init) for this case instead of the manual `for` loop